# UIMA Ruta - Gather with optional annotation

Tags: uima, ruta

I need to gather a few annotations to create a new annotation. For example, suppose

a is marked as annotation A

b is marked as annotation B

c is marked as annotation C

I want to create another annotation D that has A,B and C as features, but B needs to be optional.

A B? C{-> GATHER D, 1, 2, "a" = 1, "b" = 2, c=3)};

This does not work if B is missing, and I understand that it is because of the numbers associated. Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you use an older version of UIMA Ruta? For UIMA Ruta 2.3.0, the problem with optional rule elements was fixed in [UIMA-4233](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/UIMA-4233)

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine. Your example with some syntax corrections and some prerequisites:

```
DECLARE A, B, C;
DECLARE D (A a, B b, C c);

"a" -> A;
"b" -> B;
"c" -> C;

A B? C{-> GATHER(D, 1, 2, "a" = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = 3)};
```

... tested on text "a b c a c" with UIMA Ruta 2.4.0

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*